# List of intents and registered apps for those intents?

Tags: settings, operating-system, intents

Is it possible to view a list of intents and which application is set to launch when such intent is issued by an application? It would be nice if the OS provided such a feature where you could also change this as desired or even clear this setting for any intent so that the user would have to choose from a list of apps to open the intent with when the intent is issued. It would also be nice if on such screen one could make exceptions for apps which would open a different application than the default one for a given intent (and this could thus be set on an app-by-app basis).

Comment: There are a couple of apps doing exactly that, see my list "[Manage Default Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_5)".

Comment: Thanks for the list, but couldn't find what I was looking for (an app which actually lists the intents by their name with all the dots separating the various parts of the intent name). Anyways, for an app which opens an intent you can clear it from being the default app. I wish I could get the [Intent Analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apartapps.android.intentanalyser) and [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) apps to work but they're not working for me (interception fails).

Comment: If you want to explore an app's intents, all I can think of are apps like [Activity Launcher](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) (Apex Launcher has that functionality built-in as well). But those won't show you where they are used.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `adb shell dumpsys package`?

Comment: No I haven't. As a matter of fact I've just installed Android Studio, but when I type adb at the DOS prompt I get command not found.